# Auto Fill Row B with the last four characters of Row A

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

So basicly i want a VBA script to fill Row B with the last four characters that are in Row A

RowA contains a telephone number with around 12 numbers in it.

Comment: Do you know the `RIGHT` function in Excel? Not sure you even need a macro for this. `=RIGHT(A1,4)` in `B1` would do it... - and I think you mean "column A", not "row A".

Comment: Honestly i've never used Excel before and yes i ment column sorry.

Comment: Thanks,  Floris i must have mis interpreted you're comment.

I feel kind of bad now about my previous comment!
Hope you can excuse me for that :/

Comment: @BW don't worry. It's part of being new to the site. We are all here to learn. Apology accepted. Suggest you now delete your comment, and I will delete my response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you meant to say

> I have a series of telephone numbers in column A. I would like to
>   create a second column in which I have just the last four digits of
>   these numbers. I am new to Excel. Could someone please help me get
>   started on this?"

The answer would go like this:

In Excel you can create formulas that compute "something" - often based on the contents of other cells. For your specific situation, there is a function called `RIGHT(object, length)` which takes two arguments:

```
object = a string (or a reference to a string)
length = the number of characters (starting from the right) that you want.
```

You can see this for yourself by typing the following in a cell:

```
=RIGHT("hello world", 5)
```

When you hit `<enter>`, you will see that the cell shows the value `world`.

You can extend this concept by using a cell reference rather than a fixed string. Imagine you have "hello world" in cell A1. Now you can put the following in cell B1:

```
=RIGHT(A1, 5)
```

and you will see the value "world" in B1.

Now here is the cool trick. Assume you have a bunch of numbers in column A (say starting at row 2, since row 1 contains some header information - the title of the column). Then you can write the following in cell B2:

```
=RIGHT(A2, 4)
```

to get the last four digits. Now select that cell, and double-click on the little box in the bottom right hand corner:

[image]

Like magic, Excel figures out "you want to do this with all the cells in this column, for as many rows as there is data in Column A. I can do that!" - and your formula will propagate to all cells in column B, with the row number adjusted (so in row 3, the formula will be

```
=RIGHT(A3, 4)
```

etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws.Range("B2:B99")
        .Formula = "=Right(A2, 4)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
```